# bindingRedirect in Shell Extension Not Working

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, google-drive-api, machine.config, assembly-binding-redirect

I wrote a shell extension that calls Google Drive API v2 to download files. It complains about assembly version, namely it required to have System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=1.5.0.0, even though there is a  bindingRedirect rule already in the .dll.config file. Also note that the same bindingRedirect works perfectly when placed in the machine.config file. Is this some kind of a bug?

Comment: I suspect it's app-level config.

Comment: @Athari, I check the app-level config, i.e. app.dll.config in the application's install directory, and there everything seems to be OK. Thanks

Comment: So are you saying that it works on your machine, but not on another machine? Or just that you moved the bindingRedirect over to the higher level config?

Comment: @code4life, it works on my machine only when I add bindingRedirect ruule to the machine.config file.

Comment: Now I discovered that explorer.exe.config also works for bindingRedirect, but I'd like it to read the redirect rules from the application config.file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by writing this:

```
 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
 {
      var assembly = Assembly.Load("System.Net.Http.Primitives");

      return assembly;
 };
```